# Getting correct ContentSize.height of TableView

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, tableview, nslayoutconstraint

I have `UITableView` inside of `UIScrollView`. After I fetched some data from server,I reloaded tableview and after that I get tableview content height and change the height of tableView to that content height and call `layoutIfNeed()` on `scrollView`.

But the problem is that the contentHeight is not correct when access after `tableView` is reloaded but if access one sec later it's giving the correct height. Is there any way to get correct height without waiting for a few sec.

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
self.tableViewHeight.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height
self.containerSV.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 8):

After `reload` correct `contentSize` will only be available once all the cells are loaded. You can use `Key Value Observing` for observing changes in content size.

```
// register observer 
tableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: [.new, .old, .prior], context: nil)

@objc override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {        
    if keyPath == "contentSize" {
         // content size changed
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I was searching years for this!

Answer (score 1):

You can get correct contentSize without using KVO by doing this:

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.tableViewHeight.constant = self.tableView.contentSize
   self.containerSV.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

As main queue is serial, task with getting contentSize to it will execute only when reloading tableview is finished.